# Vim+ZenCoding. How can I get SublimeText2-like behaviour?

Tags: vim, emmet

I start using vim with zencoding plugin. For example, I type div, hit mapkey and get this (where I is cursor position):

```
<div>I</div>
```

If then I will hit *enter*, I'll get this:

```
<div>
I</div>
```

But I want to get this (like in SublimeText2 with the same zencoding plugin):

```
<div>
    I
</div>
```

How can I do it? Maybe there are some settings in zencoding plugin or secret mapkey in vim?

ps Sorry for my English.

**UPD** I try to use SparkUp, but it doesn't work at all. I have Python 2.7 and *"filetype ... on"* line in my vimrc file, but it still doesn't work. Why? I don't know.
And about surround plugin. It's not the same, it's like using snippets.

Comment: Surround and Zen/Sparkup/Snipmate serve two different purposes. Surround is when you think "here is my content, I want it to be a `p`" or "this title is not that important, I must make it a `h2`". The others are when you think "here I will put a `div`" or "OK, I need a `table` with 3 `tr`s with 4 `td`s each".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This mapping works for me:

```
inoremap <C-Return> <CR><CR><C-o>k<Tab>
```

In detail:

- `inoremap` means this is an *INSERT* mode mapping
- `<C-Return>` means I have to hit `Ctrl-Return` to trigger it
- `<CR><CR>` insert two carriage returns

  ```
  <div>|</div> ==> <div>

                   |</div>
  ```
- `<C-o>` allows to type a single *NORMAL* command without leaving *INSERT* mode
- `k` is the command in question and it moves the cursor one line up

  ```
  <div>       <div>
          ==> |
  |</div>     </div>
  ```
- `<Tab>` moves the cursor to where I want it to be

  ```
  <div>      <div>
  |      ==>     |
  </div>     </div>
  ```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. I don't know about <C-o> command before. Is there difference between your keymap and this one: `<cr><Esc>O<Tab>`?

Comment: Not really in principle. I use `<C-o>` instead of `<Esc>` because I have some stuff happening automatically on `<Esc>`. I'd guess there are at least a dozen ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try [Sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup) which is an implementation of Zencoding for vim (besides zencoding.vim).

Also, you can try the [Surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697), that allows to "surround" any text object with either {, [, (, quotes or HTML/XML Tags. In visual mode, select the text object and press <kbd>S</kbd> (That's capital "S") and enter the tag. The result is what you want to try to achieve with zencoding.vim